# Active Directory as OpenID provider?

Tags: active-directory, openid

Can an Active Directory be used as an OpenID provider? WIF is an option, but it's quite complicated and not very widespread.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you can.  Just host an ASP.NET web site that itself uses Active Directory authentication, and exposes an OpenID Provider using DotNetOpenAuth.

Comment: Any links to some sample code for how to do this? The DotNetOpenAuth site has limited documentation.

Comment: To do what, exactly?  If you want to be an Active Directory relying party, you'll have to find AD documentation for that.  If you want to (also) be a DotNetOpenAuth OpenID Provider, there are samples that come with the library to demonstrate that, and some limited documentation as you've said.

Answer (score 6):

ADFS 4.0, available from Windows Server 2016 onwards, allows authentication using OpenID.

Answer (score 5):

There is also [OpenID-LDAP](http://www.openid-ldap.org) server which claims to work with AD LDAP.

Comment: I've tried configuring OpenID-LDAP-PHP, but it stores the shared secret in SESSION (bound to the enduser) so that when the server issues check_authentication request it always replies with false - it can't find the shared secret in the SESSION for the server. It is generally very crappy code, with insufficient logging and uses mt_rand for crypto. Avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use RedHat Keycloak, which leverages any LDAP or Kerberos Server as a repository to be used with OIDC or even with poor man's auth SAML.

Comment: I wonder how they do that. I saw OpenID as an available protocol to connect to AD using Keycloak, although OpenID wasn't suported by AD for a long time.