# Keycloak: How to make authentication automatic for logged-in Windows user?

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, keycloak, openid-connect

I'm trying to create a **C# application** which would use **Keycloak** for **authentication**. Currently, I'm able to log in as user using *OpenID Connect* by sending the following REST request:

```
POST
http://{server}:{port}/auth/realms/{myRealm}/protocol/openid-connect/token

Body (x-www-form-urlencoded):
    client_id    {myClient}
    username     FooBar
    password     {userPassword}
    grant_type   password
```

Sending this request results in acquiring both *access token* and *refresh token*.

Now, I would like to be able to somehow login (acquire the tokens or otherwise authenticate the user) using the *"currently active Windows session"* by which I mean that the user (existing in **Active Directory LDAP**) which is currently logged into Windows should be authenticated without providing any credentials.

The *User Federation* in my Keycloak realm already contains configuration for the AD LDAP server so all the users are now also available in the Keycloak.

I went through the Keycloak documentation (especially the sections about [LDAP and Active Directory](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#_ldap) and [Kerberos](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#_kerberos)) but didn't quite understand what exactly needs to be done in order to make it work.

I also searched here on SO but the only relevant thing I've found is [some other user mentioning that this should be possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453769/active-directory-as-openid-provider#51777485).

**Can someone point me in the right direction?**

Answer (score 2):

In keycloak terms, you are asking for SPNEGO authentication
See https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#_kerberos

In the realm authentication tab, you need to enable Kerberos
Your Browser needs to have SPNEGO enabled.  Different browsers do that differently.  You enable a specific URL for SPNEGO

Comment: I think, he specifically asked about using REST Requests and not the browser. For a C# client, the browser workflow would not work.

Comment: The rest client would need to be able to follow the SPNEGO protocol.  The OP might want to google SPNEGO REST client

Comment: I've had success with `cURL` doing automatic windows login within a domain, but haven't used with keycloak yet.. `curl --negotiate -vvvv -l -k -s -u : https://...`

Comment: I'm frustrated every time another search result leads me back here. I have a homebrew service without keycloak that supports this, and would like to migrate to keycloak for the additional capabilities and management functionality.